# Storing the right value in a two dimensional array in c. But when I tried to print the value it shows bigger value and even negative number

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, bitwise-operators

**Problem:**
**In this question I tried to solve a bitwise operator problem. Giving two number as input**
**Input will be two number. Here is some input:**

```
n = 3
k = 3
```

**Then I need to construct "a" and "b" in some way(for instance when "a = 1" then b will be one past a to <= n. The results of the comparisons are below:**

```
a b   and or xor
1 2   0   3  3
1 3   1   3  2
2 3   2   3  1
```

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Complete the following function.


void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k) 
{
    // Two dimentional array for storing the value of and or xor
    int rowOfArray = 3;
    
    int sets[rowOfArray][k];
    
    
    //For loop for a
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        int a = i + 1;
        //For loop for b
        for (int j = a; j < n; j++)
        {
            int b = j;
            b++;
            printf("{%i, %i}\n", a, b);
            //Storing and operation result to the array
            sets[0][j - 1] = a&b;
            printf("And: %i\n", sets[0][j - 1]);
            //Storing or operation result to the array
            sets[1][j] = a|b;
            printf("Or: %i\n", sets[1][j]);
            //Storing xor opertaion result to the array
            sets[2][j + 1] = a^b;
            printf("Xor: %i\n", sets[2][j + 1]);
        } 
      
    }
   
    
    //Find the biggest number in array 
    for (int i = 0; i < rowOfArray; i++)
    {
        int big;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            big = 0;
            printf("Big1: %i\n", big);
            
            if (big < sets[i][j])
            {
                big = sets[i][j];

                printf("Big2: %i\n", big);
            }
        }
        
        printf("big3: %i\n", big);
        if (big < k)
        {
            printf("%i\n", big);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%i\n", 0);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, k;
  
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    calculate_the_maximum(n, k);
 
    return 0;
}
```

I used too many printf function to show that what have I done wrong. I stored the value as I expected but later in the for loop when I tried to print the specific position integer I didn't get the correct result even sometimes I got bigger and negative number too.

**Here is the output:**

```
 3 3
{1, 2}
And: 0
Or: 3
Xor: 3
{1, 3}
And: 1
Or: 3
Xor: 2
{2, 3}
And: 2
Or: 3
Xor: 1
Big1: 0
Big1: 0
Big2: 2
Big1: 0
Big2: 120329728
big3: 120329728
0
Big1: 0
Big2: 1986993953
Big1: 0
Big2: 3
Big1: 0
Big2: 3
big3: 3
0
Big1: 0
Big1: 0
Big2: 32765
Big1: 0
Big2: 3
big3: 3
0
```

Comment: The purpose of `k` is rather unclear here. This looks like an attempted application of [*n choose k*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), but from your description it is always *n choose 2*. `k` in the code is seemingly used as an arbitrary bound, either where `n` or the number of combinations should probably be. You may want to further clarify the problem you are trying to solve, as you do not mention `k` outside of the code snippets...

Comment: ...that said, for the input `3 3`, `j` holds the values `1`, `2`, and `2`, so clearly `sets[2][j + 1]` is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) since it accesses the subarray at index `3`, when valid indices are [0, 2].

Comment: Here is the link of this problem where you can find the full details:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bitwise-operators-in-c/problem?isFullScreen=true

Answer (score 1):

As is, for the input `3 3`, `j` holds the values `1`, `2`, and `2`, so clearly `sets[2][j + 1]` is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) since it accesses the subarray at index `3`, when valid indices are [0, 2].

---

Given the [source problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bitwise-operators-in-c/problem), the issues are more clear.

`k` is simply a limit on output, and should not be used as a bound for iteration, or for calculating the storage required for the number of [*k-combinations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

It is unnecessary to store all the results at once. For each combination, each value of the operation `a ? b` (where `?` is a bitwise operator) can be tested against the value `k` and the currently stored maximum value for the given operator.

Here is a quick solution. Compile with `-DDEBUG` to see additional output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void setmax(int *dest, int value, int limit)
{
    if (value < limit && value > *dest)
        *dest = value;
}

void calc(int n, int k)
{
    int and = 0;
    int  or = 0;
    int xor = 0;

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("INFO: a   b     and  or   xor\n");
#endif

    for (int a = 1; a < n; a++) {
        for (int b = a + 1; b <= n; b++) {
            setmax(&and, a & b, k);
            setmax(&or,  a | b, k);
            setmax(&xor, a ^ b, k);

#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("INFO: %-3d %-3d   %-3d  %-3d  %-3d\n",
                    a, b, a & b, a | b, a ^ b);
#endif
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", and, or, xor);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, k;

    if (2 != scanf("%d%d", &n, &k))
        return 1;

    calc(n, k);
}
```

Sample runs:

```
./a.out <<< "3 3"
2
0
2
./a.out <<< "5 4"
2
3
3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood that and I found my bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code, you'll get stack corruption error which is due to indexing the array beyond its allocated size. Accessing memory that's not for your program is *undefined behavior*. Anything might happen. The program may crash or it may not. For my specific compiler and the fact that I ran the code in debug mode and not release mode, the program crashed with the error I mentioned.

Now to fix the error, from what you explained, you have three *columns* for *and*, *or* and *xor*. So you need to reverse the dimensions of `set` (`set[k][rowOfArray]`, better change the name to rowSize or n_columns or so). Also reverse the indexing, e.g. change `set[0][j-1]` to `set[j-1][0]` and so on. I'm not sure what you're trying to do in the second part, though.

Comment: @Oka Actually I used MSVC to compile the code. I know the question is tagged c and not c++. Thank you, I'll edit my answer.